# How to create a flashing record button for iPhone

Tags: xcode, ios5, uibutton, avaudiorecorder

I've looked at several posts, including [this one].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994310/how-to-get-a-blinking-button-two-alternating-pictures) This is exactly what I want to do, but I cannot get it to work.

I want to show the user that they have pressed a record button, and that they will need to press it again to stop recording.

So far, the code for the start recording method looks like this:

```
NSLog(@"DetailVC - recordAudio -  soundFilePath is %@", soundFile);
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
        recording = YES;
        NSLog(@"start recording");
        NSLog(@"1");
        //[autoCog startAnimating];

        [audioRecorder recordForDuration:120];
        recording = NO;

        //Start a timer to animate the record images
        if (recording == YES) {
        toggle = FALSE;
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                                          target: self
                                                        selector: @selector(toggleButtonImage:)
                                                        userInfo: nil
                                                         repeats: YES];  


        //UIImage *changeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:stopButtonFile];       
        //[recordButton setImage:changeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];        


        //[timer invalidate];
        //timer = nil;

        NSLog(@"2");

        }
```

and the toggleButton method looks like this:

```
- (void)toggleButtonImage:(NSTimer*)timer
{
   NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    if(toggle)
    {
        NSLog(@"1");
        /*
        [UIView beginAnimations];
        recordButton.opacity = 0.0;
        [recordButton setAnimationDuration: 1.5];
        [recordButton commitAnimations];
        [recordButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
         */
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn]; //delete "EaseOut", then push ESC to check out other animation styles
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];//how long the animation will take
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
        recordButton.alpha = 1.0; //1.0 to make it visible or 0.0 to make it invisible
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    else 
    {
         NSLog(@"2");
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut]; //delete "EaseOut", then push ESC to check out other animation styles
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];//how long the animation will take
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
        recordButton.alpha = 0.0; //1.0 to make it visible or 0.0 to make it invisible
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        //[recordButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stopGrey.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
}
```

I get to see the logs showing that the loop is iterating, but:

1. the images do not switch, and
2. the operation is not running in parallel with the record method.

I would appreciate any ideas as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on Ashley's answer, I'd go with something more like this:

```
- (IBAction)record:(id)sender {
    self.recording = !self.recording;

    if (!self.recording) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 
                              delay:0.0 
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         self.recordButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
    } else {
        self.recordButton.alpha = 1.0f;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                              delay:0.0 
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                         animations:^{
                             self.recordButton.alpha = 0.0f;
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt. It worked for me! However note that when the alpha reaches less than 0.02, all touch events are ignored. 
check this question and my comment on it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499817/does-uibutton-become-disabled-when-its-alpha-is-set-to-0-0

Comment: @CSstudent : Right. You can keep the alpha to something greater than  rather than 0.1 if you need touches on the button. Wouldn't create much difference visually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)record:(id)sender 
{
    self.recording = !self.recording;

    [self toggleButton];
}

- (void) toggleButton
{
    if (!self.recording) {
        self.recordButton.alpha = 1.0;
        return;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 
                          delay: 0.0 
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                     animations:^{
                         self.recordButton.alpha = !self.recordButton.alpha;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self toggleButton];
                     }];

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashley, your code looks cool but I must be doing something else wrong, as it's not working for me.. +1 though, as I like your use of blocks, and when I figure out what I've mucked up, I will use your snippet.