# Can't touch during ""Moving"" animation (Block Animation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a View with `UIButton`, `UITextField`, and a `UIImageView` for Background.

in `viewDidLoad` i try animate `UIImageView` from alpha=0 to alpha =1 using block. it's pretty basic, here's the code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:20.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.movingImg.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x,button.frame.origin.y, self.movingImg.frame.size.width, self.movingImg.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

which is working fine. but during that 1.5 seconds of animation, my touch in current view seems to be disabled. i can't click on the image that is moving (animation is according to position).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: no it does not works even if we set alpha to 0.1  because the image is moving and i want touch this image while it is moving

Comment: where are u set your Alpha value?

Comment: inside animation block !!!!!

Comment: can you show me your complete code related animation?

Comment: I think you need to post the code which does the alpha change. The code shown seems to be for animating an image to a button position.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want to do. To move the image to a button position not to change its opacity using alpha

Comment: You need to update the question text as you ask about alpha animation. If it is a UIImageView you are moving, how are you detecting touches on the UIImageView? Perhaps you should use a UIButton with the background set as your image and move that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the alpha level to 0.01. That is the lowest Alpha according to the Apple Documentation which allows touch to work.

See [Does UIButton become disabled when its alpha is set to 0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499817/does-uibutton-become-disabled-when-its-alpha-is-set-to-0-0)