# Button click event not fire

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Currently, I am working with one UI where I need button click It works perfectly when button alpha is 1 when I change it to 0 I can't get button touch event?
Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does UIButton become disabled when its alpha is set to 0.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499817/does-uibutton-become-disabled-when-its-alpha-is-set-to-0-0)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13500095/4475605

Answer (score 3):

From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html):

> To hide a view visually, you can either set its hidden property to YES
>   or change its alpha property to 0.0. A hidden view does not receive
>   touch events from the system. However, hidden views do participate in
>   autoresizing and other layout operations associated with the view
>   hierarchy. Thus, hiding a view is often a convenient alternative to
>   removing views from your view hierarchy, especially if you plan to
>   show the views again at some point soon.

Comment: Would be nice if you would provide a link to the apple docs as well :-)

Comment: Creating and configuring view objects, part of the documentation clearly states this.

Comment: @d4Rk you can check it out the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html