# Swift: Gesture Recognizer doesn't register Taps after changing alpha to 0 and back to 1

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

the `UIView` in question is `headerView`:

```
    if isShown {
        stack.alpha = 1.0
        self.isStackShown = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.headerView.isHidden = !isShown
            self.stack.addArrangedSubview(self.headerView)

            // add touch gesture recognizer to stack view header
            let tapFind = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleFindTap))
            self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapFind)
        }
    } else {
        stack.alpha = 0.0
        self.isStackShown = false
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.headerView.isHidden = isShown
            self.stack.removeArrangedSubview(self.headerView)
        }
    }
```

The tap gesture recognizer is not registering any taps
`self.stack` is the stack view which contains the `headerView`
The condition for either showing or hiding the `headerView` is being handled in a different method and just passes the boolean `self.isStackShown` to this method to show/hide accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499817/does-uibutton-become-disabled-when-its-alpha-is-set-to-0-0

Comment: Do you see the `headerView` after adding it back to the stack when its alpha is set to 1.0?

Comment: @SanthoshR yes the stack is visible, only the touch events are not being registered. In Storyboard, its userInteraction is checked as enabled.

Comment: @J.Doe thanks so much, I'm trying with 0.05 alpha as per the suggestion in the link. Still same result, no luck.

Comment: @asdiu try it with 0.12, does that work?

Comment: tried to up it to 0.12 but no luck @J.Doe not sure how to make that tap recognizable.

Comment: Are you intending to use a `UIGestureRecognizer` instead of a `UITapGestureRecognizer`? `UIGestureRecognizer` is a polymorphic base class and should really be subclassed. `UITapGestureRecognizer` is one such subclass for handling taps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `UIGestureRecognizer`. `UIGestureRecognizer` is a polymorphic base class and should really be subclassed. `UITapGestureRecognizer` is the concrete subclass for handling taps. Use it instead.

```
let tapFind = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleFindTap))
self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapFind)
```

Your action is never getting called because `UIGestureRecognizer` has no inherent information about what kind of gesture to recognize. Only a concrete subclass of it does.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding multiple gesture recognizers when changing back the alpha to 1.0 and they aren't able to recognize simultaneously. Remove all gesture recognizers when hiding and removing the headerView since you don't need one anymore and add one back when adding back the headerView and it should work. Or you can also let the gesture recognizer be when hiding the headerView since it won't work anyway and check if one exists before adding another.

```
if isShown {
    stack.alpha = 1.0
    self.isStackShown = true
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.headerView.isHidden = !isShown
        self.stack.addArrangedSubview(self.headerView)

        // add touch gesture recognizer to stack view header
        let tapFind = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleFindTap))
        self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapFind)
    }
} else {
    stack.alpha = 0.0
    self.isStackShown = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.headerView.isHidden = isShown
        self.headerView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach({self.headerView.removeGestureRecognizer($0)})
        self.stack.removeArrangedSubview(self.headerView)
    }
}
```

or

```
if isShown {
    stack.alpha = 1.0
    self.isStackShown = true
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.headerView.isHidden = !isShown
        self.stack.addArrangedSubview(self.headerView)
        if self.headerView.gestureRecognizers?.isEmpty != false{
           // add touch gesture recognizer to stack view header
           let tapFind = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleFindTap))
           self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapFind)
        }
    }
} else {
    stack.alpha = 0.0
    self.isStackShown = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.headerView.isHidden = isShown
        self.stack.removeArrangedSubview(self.headerView)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Santhosh.R thank you for replying. I tried both approaches and they don't seem to work for me. One strong thing however is when I add a button to that `headerView`, when tapped, the button remains in selected mode and does not unselect. Any idea?