# Issue with flash animation with record button swift

Tags: swift, animation, uibutton

I am trying to make a record button so when user click on it and it's start recording and I want to apply flash animation on that button and I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605789/how-to-create-a-flashing-record-button-for-iphone) post. And I convert that code into swift but it is not working and here is my swift code:

```
var buttonFlashing = false
@IBAction func record(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("Button Tapped")
    if !buttonFlashing {
        startFlashingbutton()
    } else {
        stopFlashingbutton()
    }
}

func startFlashingbutton() {

    buttonFlashing = true
    recordButton.alpha = 1

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5 , delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

        self.recordButton.alpha = 0

        }, completion: {Bool in
    })
}

func stopFlashingbutton() {

    buttonFlashing = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {

        self.recordButton.alpha = 1

        }, completion: {Bool in
    })
}
```

It is printing `"Button Tapped"` for first time when I press button and animation takes place but when I press button again `"Button Tapped"` is not printing into console. And I can not stop animation.

I can not find what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the alpha is set to zero. So, OS disables the interaction when the alpha is zero or is hidden. The animation is applied to the layer of the button, and it already sets the alpha to the final value. So, you could set the alpha value to as low as 0.1 just to enable the user interaction and that should be fine.

You could do either one of the following options,

Set the alpha to 0.1

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5 , delay: 0.0, options: 
  [
    UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, 
    UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse,
    UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, 
    UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction
  ], 
  animations: {
    self.recordButton.alpha = 0.1        
  }, completion: {Bool in
})
```

Or, then set the color of the layer to clearColor which seems more sensible in your case.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5 , delay: 0.0, options: 
  [
    UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, 
    UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse,
    UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, 
    UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction
  ], 
  animations: {
    self.recordButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor       
  }, completion: {Bool in
})
```