# How to make a UIButton auto blink?

Tags: objective-c

Hi i am trying to make a uibutton to blink automatically. i am aware that there is a function "shows touch on highlight" which blink when user touch but i need my button to blink automatically. Is there any way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: change the background image using timer.

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994310/how-to-get-a-blinking-button-two-alternating-pictures

Answer (score 3):

First of all: **Don't do that!!!**

But if you do then you could
set timers or use `performSelector ...withDelay:` or similar stuff to trigger the switching of the images.

Or make the button transparent and layout it on top of a `UIImageView`. A `UIImageView` can be set up with an array of images, rather than a single image only, and a time interval used to swap from one image of the array to the next. See the docs for details. It is pretty straigt forward.